# Vectorized column selection

Tags: r, switch-statement, tidyverse

How can I use one column's value (eg, `x` below) to select among values among possible columns, when the selection is specific to each row?

The `x` variable determines whether variable `a`, `b`, or `c` should be selected for a given row.  Here's a simplified example; the real cells *aren't* a concatenation of the column name and row number.

```
library(magrittr); requireNamespace("tibble"); requireNamespace("dplyr")

ds <- tibble::tibble(
  x   = c(  1 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   1 ),
  a   = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"),
  b   = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"),
  c   = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")
)
```

The desired columns are values are:

```
# ds$y_desired      <- c("a1", "a2", "b3", "c4", "a5")
# ds$column_desired <- c("a" , "a" , "b" , "c" , "a" )
```

Of course the following doesn't produce a single column, but fives columns.

```
ds[, ds$column_desired]
```

And the following produces the error:
 `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : basic_string::_M_replace_aux`.

```
ds %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    y = .[[column_desired]]
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

If my real scenario had only two or three choices, I'd probably use nested-ifs,  but I'd like a generalized mapping approach to accommodate a larger number of conditions.

```
ds %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    y_if_chain = ifelse(x==1, a, ifelse(x==2, b, c))
  )
```

Ideally the approach could be directed by a lookup table, or some other metadata object like:

```
ds_lookup <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x,    ~desired_column,
  1L,                "a",
  2L,                "b",
  3L,                "c"
)
```

I'm sure this column switching question has been asked before, but I didn't find one that applied.

I'd prefer a [tidyverse](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/15/tidyverse-1-0-0/) solution (b/c that's what my team is most comfortable with), but I'm open to any tool.  I couldn't figure out how to use a combination of [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) and [kimisc::vswitch](http://krlmlr.github.io/kimisc/vswitch.html).

Comment: `names(ds)[-1][ds$x]` and `paste0(names(ds)[-1][ds$x], 1:nrow(ds))`

Comment: also alt for part 2) `df1 = as.data.frame(ds)[-1] ; df1[cbind(seq_along(ds$x), ds$x)]` (imo no need for packages)

Comment: The real dataset doesn't have cells that are a concatenation of the column name and row number, so the example's clean pattern can't be leveraged.  I'll edit the post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ds$y_desired = apply(ds, 1, function(r) r[as.integer(r[1])+1])
```

Comment: thanks for showing me how to use `apply()` here.  Until your solution, I wasn't appreciating that `r` is a vector that was cast to character.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your data is in the wrong format for what you need. First, I would convert to long from wide format with `tidyr::gather()`:

```
library("tidyr")
ds %>% 
  gather(y, col, a:c)

# A tibble: 15 × 3
#        x     y   col
#    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1      1     a    a1
# 2      1     a    a2
# 3      2     a    a3
# 4      3     a    a4
# 5      1     a    a5
# 6      1     b    b1
# 7      1     b    b2
# 8      2     b    b3
# 9      3     b    b4
# 10     1     b    b5
# 11     1     c    c1
# 12     1     c    c2
# 13     2     c    c3
# 14     3     c    c4
# 15     1     c    c5
```

Then the task becomes as trivial as `filter`ing on your required conditions (e.g. `x == 1, y == a`, etc.)

Comment: I like how your restructure makes the logic easier, and got me out of thinking there had to be an apply/switch solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @sirallen and @Phil for showing me a better way.  Here is what I've ended up using, if it helps anyone in the future.  It's generalized to accommodate

- arbitrary positions of the columns,
- arbitrary values of `x`, and
- a metadata table maps the `x` value to the desired column
  (ie, `a`, `b`, & `c`).

The given observed dataset and the lookup dataset:

```
ds <- tibble::tibble(
  x   = c( 10 ,  10 ,  20 ,  30 ,  10 ),
  a   = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"),
  b   = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"),
  c   = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")
)

ds_lookup <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x ,    ~desired_column,
  10L,                "a",
  20L,                "b",
  30L,                "c"
)
```

Encapsulating the mapping between the character vector `r` and the lookup table.

```
determine_y <- function( r ) {
  # browser()
  lookup_row_index <- match(r['x'], ds_lookup$x)
  column_name      <- ds_lookup$desired_column[lookup_row_index]
  r[column_name]
}

ds$y <- apply(ds, 1, function(r) determine_y(r))
```

Comment: minor comment is that this uses a loop and is not vectorised

Answer (score 0):

I reread Hadley's [chapter on functionals](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html) after learning from @sirallen's answer.  Here are solutions that use `switch` with other members of the apply family, including the Tidyverse-style of chaining.

```
library(magrittr); requireNamespace("purrr"); requireNamespace("tibble"); requireNamespace("dplyr")

ds <- tibble::tibble(
  x   = c( 10 ,  10 ,  20 ,  30 ,  10 ),
  a   = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"),
  b   = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"),
  c   = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")
)
determine_2 <- function( ss, a, b, c) {
  switch(
    as.character(ss),
    "10"    =   a,
    "20"    =   b,
    "30"    =   c
  )
}

# Each of these calls returns a vector.
unlist(Map(        determine_2, ds$x, ds$a, ds$b, ds$c))
mapply(            determine_2, ds$x, ds$a, ds$b, ds$c)
parallel::mcmapply(determine_2, ds$x, ds$a, ds$b, ds$c)                 # For Linux
unlist(purrr::pmap(list(        ds$x, ds$a, ds$b, ds$c), determine_2))

# Returns a dataset with the new variable.
ds %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    y = unlist(purrr::pmap(list(x, a, b, c), determine_2))
  )
```